# constraints not working when added on code

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to add constraint for right attribute to a label and a button programmatically but it doesn't work for right side constraint.

Button and label are on both the same UITableView and same cell. They both have simple width, height, x and y position constraints set in storyboard. I need to change the x position in code.

Following left constraint is working OK, I changed the value and it's reflected in simulator.

```
dateLabelLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel,
                                   attribute: .Left,
                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                   toItem: self.view,
                                   attribute: .Left,
                                   multiplier: 1,
                                   constant: 50
```

I just changed the `.Left` with `.Right` and even tried `.Trailing` but it doesn't work. I have double checked the storyboard and there is no red line for the Button.

```
buyButtonRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel,
                                   attribute: .Right,
                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                   toItem: self.view,
                                   attribute: .Right,
                                   multiplier: 1,
                                   constant: 50
```

edit :
constraints are added using `view.addConstraint`

Comment: Is there another constraint set in Storyboard that's conflicting? I know you said there's no red line, but check all the constraints in the inspector on the right.

Comment: I just removed all constraints from other objects and re-added the ones for the button, but the result is same.

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, so it's gotta be elsewhere. You can try posting the full VC to see if anyone can spot a problem.

Comment: You say that the X position is set in the storyboard - what is that constraint?  It sounds like it is conflicting with the constraint you are adding so you either need to modify the storyboard constraint at runtime or deactivate it when you add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to add constraints programmatically if you have added from storyboard....alternatively you can create the IBOutlet of specific constraints and can change the constant value of constraint you mapped programmatically.

Comment: I need to change them according to device (if it is a phone or a pad). So I already added IBOutlets for them.

Comment: Yes according to device you can change constant value  of constraints if your constraints are universal.

Answer (score 0):

You realize that creating an NSLayoutConstraint does nothing? You have to add it to a view as well.

Comment: I should have written that to OP, they are added using `view.addConstraint`